# Way to deal with repetitious parameter declaration?

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, arguments, language-features

So yes, as the title says, is there was a way to deal with repetitious parameters easily?

For example, say I'm making a class with many methods. Let's say most of the methods take the same method signature and it's rather long. Made up example:

```
void Method(int x, int y, int z = 0, string label = null, isNeverGonnaGiveYouUp = true)
```

I'm aware you can make an alias for a class...

```
using Alias = System.Console;
```

I haven't found anything similar for method parameters and didn't know if I was left to repeatedly copy and paste for everything, (and all changes). Or maybe it's possible with macros or something? Though I'm not much of a macro guy.

It'd be neat to have as a language feature. Something like...

```
using ArgList = params (int x, int y, int z = 0, string label = null, isNeverGonnaGiveYouUp = true)
void Method(ArgList)
```

Or for times where there's long generic parameters...

```
using GenArgList = params (Action<int, int, int, string, bool>)
```

And maybe generic methods...

```
using Gen = typeof (int, int, int string, bool)
void Method<Gen>(/* parameters here */)
```

I'm sure as with most other cases it's either not worth implementing or there's a valid reason for why it shouldn't be implemented. (Or maybe I'm just nuts and this is a terrible idea in general.) But copy/paste is getting old.

Thanks.

EDIT: Regarding the "just make it a class" argument, supercat makes a valid point. In my case I'm making a class that chains methods together LINQ style and each set of params can be different.

Comment: Why don't you encapsulate all those parameters into a class, then just pass the class in?

Comment: Well you could pass a class or even a Tuple, but if they are all the same why not just pass them through the constructor and use them as a field? IMO if you're looking for ways to prevent long list of arguments, you have a problem with your design.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault: Some operations require a lot of parameters.  A masked bitmap-copy operation, for example, would require thirteen (the destination bitmap, four numbers defining a rectangle thereon, source bitmap, four numbers defining a rectangle on that, mask bitmap, and the x,y coordinate of the mask location corresponding to the upper-left corner of the source).  If some of those values are computed just to perform the operation, forcing the creation of temporary objects purely for the purpose of holding them may not be terribly helpful.

Comment: You could vote for getting something like partial function application  from F# in new version of C#...

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is meta-progamming features, which are just about absent from C#.

Lisp, C++ and many functional languages can do what you ask, but I don't see it happening in C# any time soon.

You can use T4 text templates to generate the code, but after that you're on your own.